# change string/value in 3rd column based on value change in 6th column - awk

Tags: command-line, text-processing, awk

I am trying to figure out how to use awk to force the change of consecutive numbering in 3rd column of my file based on the value change in my 6th column, but preserving the spacing?? Can somebody help?

Here is a example:

```
0.00    47258      0   33103.5   33051.0    -9.20
0.00    47258      0   33103.5   33051.0    -9.20
0.00    47258      0   34329.3   34185.7   -55.44
0.00    47258      0   34329.3   34185.7   -55.44
0.00    47258      0   32677.6   32493.5    30.22
0.00    47258      0   32677.6   32493.5    30.22
```

And I want to achieve this:

```
0.00    47258      1   33103.5   33051.0    -9.20
0.00    47258      1   33103.5   33051.0    -9.20
0.00    47258      2   34329.3   34185.7   -55.44
0.00    47258      2   34329.3   34185.7   -55.44
0.00    47258      3   32677.6   32493.5    30.22
0.00    47258      3   32677.6   32493.5    30.22
```

Comment: Does your file really have blank lines, or is that a problem with the formatting?

Comment: No the file does not have blank lines. It is just the problem of the formatting here.

Comment: So the example you got shows pairs of two lines which should have same number in 6th column. Are there cases where there's adjacent lines with different value in 6 column ? Because if your case only has pairs you can do it a bit simpler

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
awk '$6 != last {++n; last = $6} {$3 = n} 1'
```

Ex.

```
$ awk '$6 != last {++n; last = $6} {$3 = n} 1' file
0.00 47258 1 33103.5 33051.0 -9.20
0.00 47258 1 33103.5 33051.0 -9.20
0.00 47258 2 34329.3 34185.7 -55.44
0.00 47258 2 34329.3 34185.7 -55.44
0.00 47258 3 32677.6 32493.5 30.22
0.00 47258 3 32677.6 32493.5 30.22
```

Comment: Thank you it worked right away!!! Amazing!!! Thanks a lot.